# Jenkins Integration with Sonar-Scanner

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to integrate Jenkins and sonar-scanner to run Angular code. Below are the my setup and configuration.

Source code available path : /home/user/Angular
SonarQube configured path : /opt/SonarQube
Sonar-Scanner configured path : /opt/Sonar-Scanner

```
$ /opt/SonarQube/bin/. /sonar.sh start
```

SonarQube is running, and i can able to access localhost in browser with port number.

```
http://localhost:9000
```

Next i am running sonar scanner in the terminal using below command

```
sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin

INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 552ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=app
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AW9NPXPGP93qcNh5qcv5
INFO: Analysis total time: 39.071 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 41.826s
INFO: Final Memory: 12M/44M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below are the Jenkins Configuration

1) Manage Jenkins –> Global Tool Configuration –> SonarQube Scanner configured, please find the attached image.[sonar-scanner Jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3oRi.png)

2) Configure SonarQube server in Jenkins, this will communicate SonarQube Server authentication.

Log in into your SonarQube Server and find following under user bar
Go to My Account –> Security –> Generate Token

[Sonar-server token jenkins authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN5MV.png)

Now the question is, i'm running jenkins pipeline jobs to execute sonar-scanner with below command in pipeline stage

```
stage('sonar-scanner') {
        container('sonar') {
           // sh "/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin"
        }
      }
```

Please find the below jenkins Error logs below, its seems unable to reach localhost:9000

```
+ sonar-scanner -X
09:25:46.052 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /usr/lib/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
09:25:46.060 INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
09:25:46.142 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.0.0.1744
09:25:46.143 INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
09:25:46.143 INFO: Linux 5.0.0-1027-azure amd64

09:25:46.568 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
09:25:46.573 DEBUG: keyStore type is : pkcs12
09:25:46.573 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
09:25:46.573 DEBUG: init keystore
09:25:46.575 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
09:25:46.822 DEBUG: Create: /root/.sonar/cache
09:25:46.824 INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
09:25:46.824 DEBUG: Create: /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp
09:25:46.827 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
09:25:46.830 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
09:25:46.831 DEBUG: Download: http://sonarqube:9000/batch/index
09:25:46.893 ERROR: SonarQube server [http://sonarqube:9000] can not be reached
09:25:46.893 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
09:25:46.894 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
09:25:46.894 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could you please some suggest how to fix this, this would be really helpful, due to this issue entire team is affecting.

Comment: add in `/etc/hosts` record like `127.0.0.1 sonarqube`

Comment: Is the scanner running on the SonarQube machine? Otherwise localhost does not work.

Comment: I have added 127.0.0.1, but now i am getting another error 11:25:12.248 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: sonarqube: Name or service not known
 at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hi Jeroen, Yes scanner is running in sonar qube machine

Comment: Can you please any one help me on this issue